# Spring MVC 3 ModelView is always Null after submit

Tags: java, spring-mvc, controller

I'm new on Spring MVC and I have an issue, I account on you for this problem and thank in advanced.

I have a Controller and first I call this mehod:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{prestadoraId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView avaliacao2(@PathVariable("prestadoraId") Long prestadoraId, Model model) {

    Prestadora prestadora = solicitacaoService.getPrestadorabyId(prestadoraId);
    model.addAttribute("prestadora", prestadora);

    return new ModelAndView("aprovacao2","prestadora",prestadora);
}
```

My JSP (This JSP get data from the method above):

```
<form:form action="aprovacao3" method="POST" commandName="prestadora" modelAttribute="prestadora" id="aprovacaoForm3">
<input type="text" name="razao_social" id="razao_social" name="razaoSocial" size="133" maxlength="100"  value="${prestadora.razaoSocial}" required />
```

The data comes and when I submit the prestadora's data is null.

I got the submit in this method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/aprovacao3", method=RequestMethod.POST)  
  public String avaliacao2(@ModelAttribute("prestadora") Prestadora prestadora, Model model, BindingResult bindingResult) {  
    model.addAttribute("prestadora", prestadora);  
    return "redirect:/aprovacao3";  
  }
```

Well, I tried many things but it always comes null.

Best Regards
Wanderson

Answer (score 2):

can you please try by removing that 'modelAttribute="prestadora"' from form tag.And also make action like action="/aprovacao3". Make sure that it is hitting all controllers.Please give a try with these modifications. It should work.